# Efficiently deleting the older documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm storing application logs in Elasticsearch. I want to delete logs older than N months. The app uses index name *my-log-index* to write the logs. What will be the most efficient way? Some of the ways I found but not sure what will be the best way:

1. Use [Delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html). Run this periodically.
2. Use alias instead of index name like my-log-alias and rollover to new index using the [Rollover API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/indices-rollover-index.html) after every N months. Also delete old indices periodically.

First approach uses expensive delete. Also, it may only soft delete. Second one looks more efficient. Which one is better or is there a better way?

Elasticsearch version: 6.2.3 (I know it is EOL but can't upgrade right now)

Answer (score 1):

Rollover with ILM is the way to go

[Lifecycle-management](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html)

With [auto deletion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ilm-delete.html)